# Find the minimum of $a+2b+3c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Assume $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$ and all non-negative, satisfy $$c(a+b+c) \geq 2-ab$$. how to find the minimum of $$a+2b+3c$$?

---

My solution:

My method is to transform $c(a+b+c)\geq 2-ab$ into multiply form. $$(a+c)(b+c) \geq 2$$

I want to use the AM-GM inequality. $$4 \leq (a+c)(2b+2c) \leq \left(\frac{a+2b+3c}{2}\right)^2$$ then I get the answer.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik When I post this question , is at a very emergency time. I know it is wrong to post question without any attempt. Now I edit this post to add my solution. A slit different from the below solution. thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c(a + b + c) \geq 2 - ab$ implies $(a + c)(b + c) \geq 2$. So:

$a + 2b + 3c = (a + c) + 2(b + c)$. So let $x = a + c$ and $y = b + c$, then we find the min of $f(x,y) = x + 2y$ with $x\cdot y \geq 2$, and $x,y > 0$. We have:

$f(x,y) \geq x + \dfrac{4}{x} \geq 2\cdot \sqrt{x\cdot \dfrac{4}{x}} = 4$. So $f_{min} = 4$

when $x = 2$, and $y = 1$. So $a + c = 2$ and $b + c = 1$

Answer (score 1):

well this inequality can be solved and you will get something like A*B >= 2 and now there will be two case either A=1 and B =2 or A=2 and B=1 , so now you can find minimum of the given expression.

Comment: Why should $A, B$ be integer?

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+2b+3c)^2-8(a+c)(b+c)=(a-2b-c)^2\geq0,$$
which gives $(a+2b+3c)^2\geq16$ or $a+2b+3c\geq4$.

The equality occurs for $a+2b+3c=4$ and $a=2b+c$,

which gives the answer: $4$.